# Android EditText selectAll() doesn't works if one taps on the same field in android 4.x only

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to select all the text present in EditText field if one clicks on the same, right now i can achieve this by below code in android 2.x and 3.x but not in 4.0. If any one had the same problem please let me know how to resolve this.

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.passcodetext1:
        if(hasFocus) editText1.selectAll();
        break;

    case R.id.passcodetext2:
        if(hasFocus) editText2.selectAll();
        break;

    case R.id.passcodetext3:
        if(hasFocus) editText3.selectAll();
        break;

    case R.id.passcodetext4:
        if(hasFocus) editText4.selectAll();
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I have same problem. With 2.3.3 all worked, but with 4.0.4 editText.selectAll(); onClick listener doesn't work.

Comment: You can fix that issue by just adding this android:selectAllOnFocus="true" in your EditText in layout.xml.

Comment: Problem is in case when cursor already is in EditText (focused). In my case it is inventory app. if user enters invalid barcode or want to enter another code, then if cursor already is in exittext cursor just stay at start position. one way is tap on another edittext and then back. In my app i changed little bit logic an i am fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this by just adding one property in layout.xml.

```
android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
```

Earlier i was not aware of this but this is really a very good solution for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
 if(hasFocus) v.selectAll();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35527348/1504248

May be you need run something like:

```
        Editable text = edit.getText();
        if (text.length() > 0) {
            text.replace(0, 1, text.subSequence(0, 1), 0, 1);
            edit.selectAll();
        }
```

inside your `if(hasFocus)`.