# EditText's selectAll() does not select the text, instead cursor is moved to position 0

Tags: android, android-edittext

My situation is: I have a `EditText`, and under it I have a button, called "select all". It's purpose is to let the user select all the text by pressing it.
When the button is clicked, I invoke `selectAll()` on the `EditText`, but instead of selecting all text, in some cases (generally, when the cursor is already positioned within the text somewhere), the cursor is moved to position `0` (start of text) and text remains unselected. Second click on the button will then select all. But of course it should happen on first click.
From this issue: [Android EditText selectAll() doesn't works if one taps on the same field in android 4.x only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11793635/android-edittext-selectall-doesnt-works-if-one-taps-on-the-same-field-in-andr) it seems that this is a bug in android 4.0 and above. (Found no mention in Google issue tracker).
Does anyone know about a way to overcome this problem? It seems that the probelm is also in other selection methods and not only `selectAll()`.
(p.s. This question is sort of duplicate of the issue I mentioned above. But I opened another question, because the author of that issue was satisfied and selected a partial answer (of setting `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"`), while in my case and scenario it does not help me and does not solve the problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Problem caused by IME. If showed cursor drag pointer then selection must be zero width.

You need cancel drag pointer. It can be doned by change text. For example `replace`:

```
            Editable text = edit.getText();
            if (text.length() > 0) {
                text.replace(0, 1, text.subSequence(0, 1), 0, 1);
                edit.selectAll();
            }
```

We replace first symbol of text with same symbol. It cause cancel drag pointer and allow make selection without bug.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue. I solved it (using Xamarin in C#, but the equivalent Java will work) with the following code:

```
private void InitFocus()
{
    Java.Lang.Runnable rable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(()=> 
    {
        EditText maleCount = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txtMaleCount);
        maleCount.RequestFocus();
        maleCount.SelectAll();
    });
    new Handler().Post(rable);
}
```

I have 2 controls: One is a dropdown that lets you select a chicken house and then a set of buttons for each day of the week. Whenever you change the day of week or the chicken house, I want to set focus in the `txtMaleCount` `EditText` and then I want the value in that box selected (since it's a number and they're presumably going to replace it).

Clearly, the non-intuitive part was the need to `Post` it. Doing it directly (on the UI thread) didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Thanks, but also this didn't solve the problem. I tried several variations, including call `requestFocus` in my listener directly and then `handler.post()` with the `selectAll()` and other combinations. Tried also `postDelayed()` 100ms but could not solve all cases. The problematic case is when I click in the `EditText` and then on the "Select All" button. Rather, if I also type something in the `EditText` and then press the button it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
yourEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //((EditText)v).selectAll();
        ((EditText)v).setSelection(startValue, stopValue);
    }
});
```

Or This:

```
yourEditText.setOnFocusChangedListener(new OnFocusChangedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus){
        if (hasFocus){
            //((EditText)v).selectAll();
            ((EditText)v).setSelection(startValue, stopValue);
        }
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
theEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)view;
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1); // selects all the text
    }
});
```

Or this:

```
theEditText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        EditText editText = (EditText)view;
        editText.performLongClick();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: Thanks, but your answers are based on reaction to click/focus in the EditText, while I want to react to the button press. So not better than `android:selectAllOnFocus="true"` which works but does not help me.<br>I tried also `setSelection(startValue, stopValue)` and did not help and also `performLongClick()` does not help.

Comment: You can change the editText to button that does not a big deal.

Comment: Second one works for me. But ((EditText)v).setSelection(startValue, stopValue); should be ((EditText) view ).setSelection(startValue, stopValue);